# Rails Gem not loading in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I have written my own Gem called date_ninja which makes sure a date is returned in the correct when passing a date from excel. Testing the gem it works fine. For example opening irb, and calling `require 'date_ninja'` returns true and I am able to use.

```
DateNinja::DateDojo.date_format_validation(value).
```

This will either return an date or an exception.

In my Rails App, I have added the gem to my gemfile as so:

```
gem 'date_ninja', git: 'git@github.com:mpowered/date_dojo'
```

I then ran bundle install but when I use it, I get this:

```
DateNinja::DateDojo.date_format_validation(56423)
  NameError: uninitialized constant DateNinja::DateDojo
  from (pry):5:in `<main>'
```

If I open the Rails console and see if I can `require 'date_ninja'` it `=> false` so I am guessing its not loading my gem even though I have bundled it. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Would have been nice if you could have tried a little harder with your spelling and grammar to keep the site tidy. Have cleaned up for you.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for keeping me clean! ;)

Comment: Did the below answer help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try replacing the line:

```
gem 'date_ninja', git: 'git@github.com:mpowered/date_dojo'
```

with

```
gem 'date_ninja', path: 'local/path/of/ninja'
```

If this works then something is not well set with git.

Comment: thanks that lead to me finding the answer. it was finding it fine just there was an issue where when calling the method i needed to call `DateDojo::DateSensei` instead. you rock

Comment: Glad I could at least help you find the actual problem!